# R dplyr: rowwise + mutate (+glue) - how to get/refer row content?

Tags: r, dplyr, rowwise, r-glue

The simple example of input data:

```
dataset <- data.frame("part1" = c("a", "b", "c"),
                       "part2" = c("x", "y", "z"),
                       "caption" = c("{part1} {part2}",
                                     "{part2} {part1}",
                                     "{part2} {part1} {part2}"),
                       stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Expected results:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 3
  part1 part2 caption
  <chr> <chr> <chr>  
1 a     x     a x    
2 b     y     y b    
3 c     z     z c z
```

The below code doesn't work, because `.` refers to the whole `dataset`, instead of data of the whole row content:

```
dataset %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate("caption" =
           glue::glue_data(., caption)
         )
```

Question: how to pass row (all) content to `glue`?

The code that works (row "content" declared explicitly) is not what I've been looking for, because there are more columns used in `caption` "pattern" in my data set, thus I would like to avoid to declare it manually, just pass the whole row content.

```
dataset %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate("caption" =
           glue::glue_data(
             list("part1" =  part1,
                  "part2" = part2)
             , caption)
  )
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works simply as:

```
dataset %>% rowwise %>% mutate(r=as.character(glue(caption)))
#Source: local data frame [3 x 4]
#Groups: <by row>

## A tibble: 3 x 4
#  part1 part2 caption                 r    
#  <chr> <chr> <chr>                   <chr>
#1 a     x     {part1} {part2}         a x  
#2 b     y     {part2} {part1}         y b  
#3 c     z     {part2} {part1} {part2} z c z
```

NOTE : I added the `as.character`only to avoid warnings that seem to be an issue with `rowwise`(`Vectorizing 'glue' elements may not preserve their attributes`)