# Replacing placeholder values in dataframe with values from another column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df <-
  structure(
    list(
      Exception1 = c(
        "Comments from {2}: {0}",
        "status updated to {1} by {2}. Description:{0}",
        "status updated to {1} by {2}. Description:{0}",
        "information only.",
        "status updated to {1} by {2}. Description:{0}",
        "status updated to {1} by {2}. Description:{0}"
      ),
      Exception2 = c(
        "Customer {0} said bla",
        "Status updated to {1}",
        "Customer said {2}",
        "User {0} foo",
        "{0} {1}",
        "{1} {2}"
      ),
      ARGUMENT1 = c("OK", " ", " ", "PAY9089723089-98391", " ", " "),
      ARGUMENT2 = c(
        "null",
        "Processing",
        "Reconciled",
        "null",
        "Processing",
        "Reconciled"
      ),
      ARGUMENT3 = c(
        "company name",
        "company name",
        "company name",
        "null",
        "company name",
        "company name"
      )
    ),
    row.names = c(NA, 6L),
    class = "data.frame"
  )
```

:

```
| Exception1                                    | Exception2            | ARGUMENT1           | ARGUMENT2  | ARGUMENT3    |
|-----------------------------------------------|-----------------------|---------------------|------------|--------------|
| Comments from {2}: {0}                        | Customer {0} said bla | OK                  | null       | company name |
| status updated to {1} by {2}. Description:{0} | Status updated to {1} |                     | Processing | company name |
| status updated to {1} by {2}. Description:{0} | Customer said {2}     |                     | Reconciled | company name |
| information only.                             | User {0} foo          | PAY9089723089-98391 | null       | null         |
| status updated to {1} by {2}. Description:{0} | {0} {1}               |                     | Processing | company name |
| status updated to {1} by {2}. Description:{0} | {1} {2}               |                     | Reconciled | company name |
```

The Exception1 and Exception 2 columns (there are a couple more Exception columns which I removed for readability) contain placeholders {} that are meant to be replaced with the values in the ARGUMENT* columns.

I have been looking at ways to accomplish this and have been relatively successful but I am still lacking the experience to do it better.

I wrote a simple function that does the replace through gsub:

```
excp_ren2 <- function(x) {
  x %<>%
    gsub("\\{1\\}", x["ARGUMENT2"], .) %>%
    gsub("\\{0\\}", x["ARGUMENT1"], .) %>%
    gsub("\\{2\\}", x["ARGUMENT3"], .)
  x
}
```

And then have been using apply and its variances. I have accomplished for example an OK result with this:

```
new_df <-
  df %>% apply(
    .,
    MARGIN = 1,
    FUN = function(x)
      excp_ren2(x)
  ) %>% as.data.frame()
```

with the only problem that this transposes the matrix which is not really a problem.

I am looking for better ways to do this, I thought I was going to be able to do this through mutate_* but I think I lose access to the column names for the row inside the function or at least I do not know how to do it. Any ideas on simpler ways to accomplish this?

Thanks!

Comment: You are using `apply` with `MARGIN = 1` on all the columns.  I guess you are interested only in the firsst column `Exception1 `) In that case, just apply the function on that column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of doing this by row (and applying the function on each column rather than 'Exception1'), we can use `str_replace` (which is vectorized) in a pipe

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  transmute(new =  str_replace_all(Exception1, "\\{1\\}", ARGUMENT2) %>% 
                   str_replace_all("\\{0\\}", ARGUMENT1) %>% 
                   str_replace_all("\\{2\\}", ARGUMENT3))
#                                                  new
#1                                  Comments from company name: OK
#2 status updated to Processing by company name. \\nDescription:\n
#3 status updated to Reconciled by company name. \\nDescription:\n
#4                  PCard order invoices are for information only.
#5 status updated to Processing by company name. \\nDescription:\n
#6 status updated to Reconciled by company name. \\nDescription:\n
```

---

If we have multiple columns, we can make use of `mutate_at` or `transmute_at`

```
df %>%
   transmute_at(vars(starts_with("Exception")), ~ 
           str_replace_all(., "\\{1\\}", ARGUMENT2) %>% 
                   str_replace_all("\\{0\\}", ARGUMENT1) %>% 
                   str_replace_all("\\{2\\}", ARGUMENT3))
#                    Exception1                   Exception2
#1                              Comments from company name: OK         Customer OK said bla
#2 status updated to Processing by company name. Description:  Status updated to Processing
#3 status updated to Reconciled by company name. Description:    Customer said company name
#4                                           information only. User PAY9089723089-98391 foo
#5 status updated to Processing by company name. Description:                    Processing
#6 status updated to Reconciled by company name. Description:       Reconciled company name
```

Comment: This is nice but it takes just one of the Exception columns and there are more. How would you advise to take into account i.e Exception2, Exception3 and Exception4?

Comment: I edited the original post to include one additional Exception column to explain better what I mean

Comment: @PauloCalvo. Are the same columns 'ARGUMENT1', 2, 3, applied to all of the columns?

Comment: Yes, same ARGUMENTs replace in all Exception columns.

Comment: @PauloCalvo Updated the post

Comment: Awesome thank you, I spent too much time looking at mutate and never looked at transmute.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this

```
clean_pipe <- . %>% 
  mutate(new_string = Exception1 %>% str_replace_all(pattern = "\\{0\\}",replacement = ARGUMENT1)) %>% 
  mutate(new_string = new_string %>% str_replace_all(pattern = "\\{1\\}",replacement = ARGUMENT2)) %>% 
  mutate(new_string = new_string %>% str_replace_all(pattern = "\\{2\\}",replacement = ARGUMENT3))

df %>% 
  clean_pipe
```

Answer (score 1):

The way you used `{ }` to demarcate made me think of using [`glue`](https://glue.tidyverse.org/), which operates in a similar way. To make glue templates that match the column names in your data, first use a named list in `stringr::str_replace_all` to match patterns with replacements all in one step. Then create the `glue` objects from the `"Exception*"` columns. Based on this post ([R dplyr: rowwise + mutate (+glue) - how to get/refer row content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52403164/5325862)), you'll need to use `rowwise` because otherwise it will try to use *all* the values of each argument column for *each* template. I'd wanted to put both `mutate_at` steps into one function, but had some trouble with scoping, so this was the neatest I could get working.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

replacements <- c("\\{1\\}" = "{ARGUMENT2}",
                  "\\{0\\}" = "{ARGUMENT1}",
                  "\\{2\\}" = "{ARGUMENT3}")

as_tibble(df) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Exception")), stringr::str_replace_all, replacements) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(starts_with("Exception")), ~as.character(glue::glue(.)))
#> Source: local data frame [6 x 5]
#> Groups: <by row>
#> 
#> # A tibble: 6 x 5
#>   Exception1                  Exception2       ARGUMENT1     ARGUMENT2 ARGUMENT3
#>   <chr>                       <chr>            <chr>         <chr>     <chr>    
#> 1 Comments from company name… Customer OK sai… OK            null      company …
#> 2 "status updated to Process… Status updated … " "           Processi… company …
#> 3 "status updated to Reconci… Customer said c… " "           Reconcil… company …
#> 4 information only.           User PAY9089723… PAY908972308… null      null     
#> 5 "status updated to Process… "  Processing"   " "           Processi… company …
#> 6 "status updated to Reconci… Reconciled comp… " "           Reconcil… company …
```

Note that because some strings are empty, you've got extra blank spaces in your result that you can trim with `trimws`.